# Issue with cordova-plugin-facebook4 installation

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, html-framework-7

been trying to get cordova-plugin-facebook4 to work with my cordova app. I am using framework7 and android platform version 6.4. I have installed the plugin successfully, setting the APP ID and NAME using:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="***" --variable APP_NAME="***"
```

Framework7 is loaded after the deviceready method, so my code is fired after the device is ready. I am building the app and debugging on my android phone.

Below the code am using on the onclick event of my facebook button:

```
var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
    alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
    facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken(function(token) {
        alert("Token: " + token);
    }, function(err) {
        alert("Could not get access token: " + err);
    });
}

facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
    fbLoginSuccess,
    function (error) { alert("" + error) }
);
```

When running the app on my android device i keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined
```

Any help would be much appreciated,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had to include cordova.js in my project, which is created upon building the app and was not visible in my project, in order for the plugins to work. Noob mistake.